# High-energy effective field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, models, effective-field-theory

Usually when one speaks of effective field theories, one is looking to integrate out certain fields which are typically heavy in comparison to the regime of interest. That is one has a theory at a high energy and obtains/writes down a matching theory where this heavy degrees of freedom have been averaged out.

Are there any notions in the community of the inverse procedure. I am looking for some procedure along the lines: Start with a theory that explains a wide regime of energies and focus on the higher energy cases by "integrating out" degrees of freedom which one expects will only contribute too little at those scales, thus obtaining an effective description for the high energy section.

Comment: No one does this, for the fairly obvious reason that the low energy modes are most important, will contribute importantly at high energies, and a theory without them would be drastically nonlocal. The reason for that is, when you integrate out modes up to some energy scale $\Delta$, you introduce nonlocality on a scale $1/\Delta$ (interactings involving exchange of modes at scale $\Delta$ are ignored so it looks like you have action at a distance of $1/\Delta$). So if you integrate out degrees of freedom $\Delta \approx 0$ then your theory is very nonlocal and nonunitary

Comment: Sure I understand the energy scale itself won't be a "proper" expansion parameter for such procedure, but perhaps some other method allows one to detach the low energy physics, analogous to a lower momentum cut-off to deal with infrared divergences. I am also sceptical about the idea on its own but seemed worth asking around...

Comment: Every monograph I've ever read on EFT is pretty adamant it's only low energy physics we care about so I'm 99% sure no one is interested. A high energy particle can emit infinitely many soft modes - that's the most important physics to parametrise. I mean, what other excitations would you want to keep track of? Those with energies greater than the scale of your experiment? Clearly those won't contribute as much, because you don't have enough energy to excite them!

Comment: Well not necessarily out of my experiment, on the contrary, I was thinking more like ignoring the physics happening let's say below the sensitivity of my detector, something of that sort. Then again, thank you for your input Julian.

Comment: Oh! Okay - what you're talking about sounds similar to the way of dealing with IR divergences/jets, idk if you're familiar with this story?

Comment: I have avoided Jets as much as possible hehe, but I guess might be worth looking into it, do you of any short primer focused on this kind of ideas?

Comment: Matt Schwartz's book has a decent section on it https://canvas.harvard.edu/files/936402/download?download_frd=1&verifier=F760LwWdmCja7JqcNpFj2C8vROjlRSTc8ZhpJkRA

Comment: I think Weinberg discusses it in Vol 2, in the section on renormalisation, but I don't quite remember. It's somewhere in Weinberg! Look up IR divergences (detector size cuts off IR divergences - more to the story than that but yeah)